# Can I use the "as" mechanism in an if statement

Tags: python, if-statement

Is it possible to use `as` in `if` statement like `with` that we use, for example:

```
with open("/tmp/foo", "r") as ofile:
    # do_something_with_ofile
```

This is my code:

```
def my_list(rtrn_lst=True):
    if rtrn_lst:
        return [12, 14, 15]
    return []

if my_list():
      print(my_list()[2] * mylist()[0] / mylist()[1])
```

Can I use `if` in this type:

```
if my_list() as lst:
     print(lst[2] * lst[0] / lst[1])
```

In first `if` I called `my_list` four times. I can use a variable but I want to know is there any way to use `as`?

Comment: In your mind, what would be the advantage of this syntax over using a variable, except for being one line shorter?

Comment: Only one line shorter ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. The `if` statement is defined as:

```
if_stmt: 'if' test ':' suite ('elif' test ':' suite)* ['else' ':' suite]
```

... where `test` is a suite of test expression combined with or/and.

For more information, see: http://docs.python.org/3.3/reference/grammar.html

You can defined your variable before and then test its value:

```
lst = my_list()
if lst:
     print(lst[2] * lst[0] / lst[1])
```

If you want some challenge (and for expiremental stuff only), you can change the Python grammar, have fun: http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0306/

Comment: Changing grammer is a nice suggestion, Thanks @Maxime ;)

Answer (score 1):

No.  The Python grammar does not allow using "`as`" outside of `with`, `except`, or `import` constructs.  You should instead do:

```
lst = my_list()
if lst:
     print(lst[2] * lst[0] / lst[1])
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a variable. `with` supports the `as`-variable because the object assigned to it is *not* the result of evaluating the `with`-expression. (It is the value returned by that result's `__enter__` method, see http://docs.python.org/release/2.5/whatsnew/pep-352.html. With (most) other statements, it's easy enough to catch the expression in a variable. I.e., `with expr as v` is (partly) equivalent to:

```
_context = expr
v = _context.__enter__()
...
```