# In django, can I use 'as' in if tags like so: {% if excessively_verbose.chain_of_long.nested_references as foo%}

Tags: python, django, if-statement, django-templates

I'm populating xml from json with an `excessively_verbose.chain_of_long.nested_references`.

Sometimes that parent level isn't there, and in an effort to reduce the padding of my template, I'd like to use something a little like this:

```
{% if excessively_verbose.chain_of_long.nested_references as foo%}
```

I've tried the above and the below:

```
{% if excessively_verbose.chain_of_long.nested_references with excessively_verbose.chain_of_long.nested_references as foo%}
```

But I'm getting `unused with/as at end of is`.

Is this possible (preferable without re-writing the `{% if %}` tag)? It seems simple, straightforward and useful (to me at least)!

I guess this is the Django equivalent of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20035655/1075247), which does not look promising

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like what you want is something more along the lines of:

```
{% with foo=excessively_verbose.chain_of_long.nested_references %}
    {% if foo %}
        {{ foo }} bar
    {% endif %}
{% endwith %}
```

Comment: Yes,  but compressed into the if tag. I'm guessing that's not possible?

Comment: I'm fairly certain that is something you cannot do in the Django Template Language or, in fact, even Python itself. This exact scenario is actually the intent behind the `with` tag. From Django's documentation, `Caches a complex variable under a simpler name. This is useful when accessing an “expensive” method (e.g., one that hits the database) multiple times.`

Comment: That makes sense. The difference with python though is you don't need an extra line to close if tags, nor with tags.